# How to querySelector across all events in FullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar, filtering

I'm working on building a filterable calendar and to do that, I set a class name on my calendar's events in it's source array. See below:

```
source.push({
    id: 5695151911,
    title: "Customer Success",
    start: "2018-05-11 15:26:05",
    end: "2018-05-11 15:26:05",
    description: "",
    url: "",
    button_txt: "",
    address: "",
    addressUnformatted: "", 
    location: "ttt",
    allDay: false,
    sameDay: same,
    eventType: "",
    // Handle classing for filters
   className: "filterable-item__groups active group1_-_English group2_-_filter1 group3_-_filter3 "
});
```

Pay attention to the className section. In there I am setting `filter-item__groups` which is what I want to query across to create my filters. As of right now, when I query, it will only pull the filters for `group1`, `group2`, and `group3` for the current month selected. I believe the problem is because the other months aren't currently in the DOM on load.

This is how I'm querying events for the correct classes:

```
const modules = document.querySelectorAll('.filterable-content');
      modules.forEach(mod => {
         const items = mod.querySelectorAll('.filterable-item__groups');
         const dropdowns = mod.querySelectorAll('.filterable-content__filters ul');
         const labels = mod.querySelectorAll('.filterable-content__selected-filters');
      });
```

**Key**

`.filterable-content` - container for my calendar

`.filterable-item__groups` - class on my event

`.filterable-content__filters ul` - UL tag that holds the filters when dynamically created.

`.filterable-content__selected-filters` - Labels that are dynamically added to the UL tag

Is there a way to query all of my events, so I can generate the filters for all the classes that exist on the entire calendar, and not just the current month?

Comment: i would suggest filtering the event list rather than the resulting HTML

Comment: @ADyson My issue is more consisting of how do I get all of the active filter classes (which are coming from a database), when they aren't stored in the DOM

Comment: you missed my point. Stop using classes to filter DOM items. Filter your _event objects_ instead. Then you can filter against all events, not just the ones on the current display which get turned into HTML DOM items. Use some other custom properties to make your queries. Maybe you should even send your filter options back to the server and let your database do the filtering via SQL queries.